# Relic Shield or Ancient Coin on Melee Supports

Tags: league-of-legends

I see that Face of the Mountain is not that effective late game with Thresh or Taric when it comes to gold income. I spectated a game from Aphromoo and I noticed that sometimes he sells his Relic Shield to get Ancient Coin.

When should I do this? I know it's situational so an example to when to do it and when not to would be good.

Comment: You've asked several questions in quick succession, and none show prior research. You'll get a much better reception here if we see you've expended some effort trying to solve your own problem.

Comment: @Frank While I agree with everything you said, it's not a horrible question. It just needs to be flushed out a bit.

Comment: @ChaseC It shows zero effort. That, right there, is downvote worthy, all by itself.

Comment: @ChaseC fleshed*

Comment: @Aequitas Fleshed. Flushed is....not correct haha

Comment: @Frank Right, agree about that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the laning phase is over and the roaming starts. Relic shield is a really good starting item because it regains health and gives both the support and adc gold.

Top tier supports will get Anicent Coin when the need the speed boost from it's active once the skirmishes start breaking out all over the map.

IF YOU ARE PLANNING ON SELLING RELIC SHIELD DO NOT UPGRADE IT PAST IT'S SECOND UPGRADE. You are then wasting gold and it's not cost effective.